# How to insert data into database in next row automatically

Tags: java

I am working on access control system with a database as a project. I want to the database to serve as a data log. That is, I am writing a program that writes the login time and logout time to the database and also logout date whenever access is granted to a user. What I am finding difficult is causing the cursor go to the next row whenever a user is inserted into the database(is logged in). Can anyone help me on how to use Java to get this done? I want each user to be inserted into database in separate row so that even if the same user logs in a day after, it goes to the next row not being updated or over written by new data log

Comment: Any code you can share? There's little we can do to help if you don't show what you've tried, or any specific error or problem.

Comment: As well as describing what you have already tried, please include what the table should look like for each step in your scenarios.

Comment: This Question is unfocused and **too broad for Stack Overflow**. This site is aimed at narrow questions about a very specific programming issue. See the [Oracle Tutorial on JDBC](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/TOC.html).

Comment: it's not that I want all those things to be sorted out f me, all I ask is help on how to make each entry into the database go to next row without specifying row

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I have figured it out. All I have to do is auto increment the raw number each time data is written into the database. When data is sent to the serial port, it will be read as strings. the string of characters which represents users card number is also available in another separate database table. The read card number is compared with those in that database table. if match is found, Names of the user having the card number will be SELECTED and written to the log table. Each time there is data in the serial port the row number is incremented.